# How to call async task from parent class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, task

Today I need your help to debug my code... Indeed, I need to use the Task object to make API calls but it don't work.

My RestClient to execute my get / post / put requests:

```
public class RestClient
{
    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

    public RestClient()
    {
        if(HttpClient == null)
        {
            HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        }
    }

    protected async Task<string> Get(string url)
    {
        // Call url in thread
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(url);

        // Get content
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return content;
    }
}
```

This problem is here, I cannot to get the return of the base.Get(url). Do you know how I can fix that ?

```
class CarEnergy : RestClient
{

    public CarEnergy Geter(int id)
    {
        string url = String.Format(Configuration.Configuration.GetCarEnergy, id);

        Debug.WriteLine(url);

        // Wait the get request before continue
        var myTask = base.Get(url); // Impossible to get the return, it bug

        Debug.WriteLine(result);

        var carEnergy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CarEnergy>>(result);

        return carEnergy[0];
    }

}
```

Comment: When you post code be sure to highlight it and press the `{ }` button on the website to make sure it is formatted properly.

Comment: Why does `CarEnergy` inherit from `RestClient` doesn't it make more sense for `CarEnengy` to *have* a rest client (store it in a variable).

Comment: Where is "result" defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Get()` method is `async`, so you have to wait for the result somehow. The best way to do this is to use `await`. That means your `Geter()` method also needs to be `async`, and its caller needs to `await`, and so on.

Note also that the `Get()` method is neither virtual or hidden, so you don't need to use `base` to call it.

Fixing the above results in something that looks like this:

```
public async Task<CarEnergy> Geter(int id)
{
    string url = String.Format(Configuration.Configuration.GetCarEnergy, id);

    Debug.WriteLine(url);

    // Wait the get request before continue
    var myTask = await Get(url);

    Debug.WriteLine(result);

    var carEnergy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CarEnergy>>(result);

    return carEnergy[0];
}
```

You can block on the async method if you must, by simply retrieving the `Result` property instead of using `await`:

```
    var myTask = Get(url).Result;
```

(In this case, obviously you don't have to change `Geter()` to be an `async` method).

But I ***strongly*** discourage doing that. When used correctly, the `async`/`await` pattern will wind up woven throughout your code, and will make all of it more UI-friendly and easier to write.